# How to detect if a roblox username is available

Tags: api, lua, roblox

How do I detect if a roblox username is available using API's? I searched the roblox api documentation (https://api.roblox.com/docs) but couldn't find anything, even searched external sources.

Comment: Check out the [auth APIs](https://auth.roblox.com/docs#!/Usernames/post_v1_usernames_validate). There's one that will let you check a username to see if it is valid, and one of the error codes will tell you if it is already taken.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand a little bit on **Kylaaa**'s answer, this is the exact endpoint you can use to check if a username is valid:

> [https://auth.roblox.com/v1/usernames/validate?request.username=[UsernameHere]](https://auth.roblox.com/v1/usernames/validate?request.username=%5BUsernameHere%5D)

Keep in mind that you cannot directly use this endpoint from a Roblox game, you will have to set up a proxy server that acts as a middleman between the game server and this endpoint:

[image: code snippet]

More on setting up your own web server: https://github.com/sentanos/ProxyService